# checkbox in uitableview with condition?

Tags: ios, uitableview, checkbox

when i select all checkbox all are checked but when i uncheck any of them and again i am click on select all option except uncheck option all are uncheck and a uncheck is checked.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath1
{
  CFCell *cell;


    if(indexPath1.row == 0)
    {
            for (int counter =0 ; counter < [self.dataTableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];counter++)
            {

                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:counter inSection:0];
                cell = (CFEquipmentCell *)[self.dataTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


                if(selectedChecks[indexPath.row]==[NSNumber numberWithInt:1])
                {
                    selectedChecks[indexPath.row] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
                    cell.Checkbox.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"];
                }
                else
                {
                    selectedChecks[indexPath.row] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
                    cell.Checkbox.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"];
                }
            }
    }


    else
    {

        cell = (CFCell *)[self.dataTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath1];


        if(selectedChecks[indexPath1.row]==[NSNumber numberWithInt:1])
        {
            selectedChecks[0] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
            selectedChecks[indexPath1.row] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];

            cell.Checkbox.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"];
        }
        else
        {
            selectedChecks[indexPath1.row] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
            cell.Checkbox.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"];
        }


    }
```

please solve my issue in code what i use for perfect working.
1) i need to be when i click on select all option select all checkbox.
2) when i uncheck any of them select all oprtion alos be uncheck.
3) when again select all option check all checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Make Below Steps:

1. Create NSMutableArray equal to Number of Rows

   Example: No Of Rows = 10

   ```
   NSMutableArray *checkmarkArray; //GLOBAL DECLARATION

   - (void)viewDidLoad    {

   checkmarkArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    for (int i=0; i<[tableData count]; i++) // tableData is Number of Rows count
   {
       [checkmarkArray addObject:@"NO"];
   }


   }
   ```
2. Second Step cellForRowAtIndexPath Changes

   ```
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
       {
       if([checkmarkArray[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"NO"])
       {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

           cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"untick.png"]];
           [cell.accessoryView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15)];

       }
       else
       {
           cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
           cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"]];
           [cell.accessoryView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15)];
       }

       }
   ```
3. Third Step Select All Button

   ```
   -(IBAction)selectall_btnclick:(id)sender
   {
    for (int i=0; i<[tableData count]; i++)
   {

       [checkmarkArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"YES"];

   }

   [tableView reloadData];
   }
   ```

   `
4. Third Step De Select All Button

   ```
   -(IBAction)deselectall_btnclick:(id)sender
   {
    for (int i=0; i<[tableData count]; i++)
   {

       [checkmarkArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"NO"];

   }

   [tableView reloadData];
   }
   ```
5. Next

   ```
   -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   if ([checkmarkArray [indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"YES"])

   {
       [checkmarkArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"NO"];
   }
   else
   {
       [checkmarkArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"YES"];
   }

   [tableView reloadData];}
   ```

This must work for your concept. Let me know you need any clarifications.

Comment: have you example without table reloading? @PREMKUMAR

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 //give your uncheck code here
}
```

give your uncheck code inside the above delegate method